# How to use multiple options for a FloatingActionButton "Speed Dial" menu in flutter?

Tags: button, methods, menu, flutter

I'm using a Speed Dial type floating menu from a floatingActionButton.  I'm populating the different icons from a list, but I'm having trouble populating the necessary `onPressed:` method.  My widget is coded like so...

```
child: new FloatingActionButton(
                heroTag: "Y${icons[index]}",
                backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                mini: true,
                child: new Icon(icons[index], color: Colors.white),
                onPressed: () {print("hello");},
              ),
```

All my icons successfully print "hello".  How can I make them use different methods or specifically Navigations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<VoidCallback> functions = [(){
    print("hello 1");
}, () {
    print("hello 2");
}];
```

You can use it as `functions[index]`